# How Do I Align Text Vertically in a Round Button?

Tags: css

I’m trying to create resizing buttons using CSS. Here’s what I have so far (onclick handlers will come later).

It’s almost correct, except the text in the last button (just a hyphen), isn’t centered vertically. The first two buttons are vertically centered as intended, but not the *last* button.

Can anyone see what I’m doing wrong? I’m guessing it might something inherent in the way the dash character is designed in this font. It that’s the case, can anyone suggest a better Unicode dash character that would properly align vertically?

```css
body {
  background-color: Aqua;
}

.button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.button div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.button:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .4cm;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Resizer Buttons</h1>
    <span class="button"><div>+</div></span>
    <span class="button"><div>×</div></span>
    <span class="button"><div>–</div></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Comment: try to add `line-height: .8em;` on your `.button` style (not a very elegant solution indeed)

Comment: I would use images and not characters. The size isn't constant, and it makes everything glitchy.

Comment: Your `font-size: 200%` (by default 200% of 16px ) with an average `line-height` around `1.2`   makes a total size of 1.2 * 2 * 16px = 38.4px  is simply too large to fit in a `25px` space. Use CSS `* { outline: 1px dashed }` and you can see the button contents overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Rene. I converted the button CSS to flex (suggested in other answers, then added the outline: 1px dashed, and now everything seems to be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<span class="button"><div>&#x2212;</div></span>` for the last button. Also, when I tried your code in my computer the text in the buttons didn't center vertically and I changed the display property of button class to flex. You might want to consider doing that as well.

Comment: Wow! Code &#x2212; was exactly what I needed. Seems to work perfectly, at least on my machine.Thanks for the quick turnaround!

Answer (score 1):

A note first: In the snippet you posted, also the first two button's contents are *not* properly center-aligned vertically.

BUT: If you add `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;` to the CSS rule for `.button`, the alignment works as intended.

This changes the `display` property from `block` to `flex`, in this case "vertical flex" (i.e. `flex-direction: column`)  and (vertically) centers the contents using `justify-contents: center`

```css
body {
  background-color: Aqua;
}

.button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 200%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button div {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.button:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .4cm;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>Resizer Buttons</h1>
  <span class="button"><div>+</div></span>
  <span class="button"><div>×</div></span>
  <span class="button"><div>–</div></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:flex` for the `button` instead of `block`. Then you can use `align-items:center` and `justify-content`center` like this:

```
    .button {
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid black;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 200%;
    }
```

You will need to work with the **minus** symbol for your last button because it doesn't play well with the alignment. Sunay's suggestion sounds like a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks! Converting to flex did the trick! My original code was  based on the example at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_circles.  Flex is clearly a better solution! Thanks!